# Not able to get element count having dynamic xpath

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My xpath is like-

```
//*[@id='xyz']/div [0]/form [1]
```

Numbers 0 and 1 are changing.
I can manage 0 using for loop. But form number is dynamic`enter code here`

```
For (int i = 0; i <element. Count; i++)
{

List l = driver.findElements ( By.xpath (//*[@id='xyz']/div [i]/form [1]
}
```

In above for loop form [number] is dynamic.for each element in above for loop there are multiple forms. So not able to get exact number of elements in list.

I need a loop. Page is like-

```
Model1
-ofr1
-ofr2
-ofr3


Model2
-ofr1
-ofr2
```

No.of Offers are changing
In loop i want Model1 & need to do operation on all its offers, model2 & all its ofrs & soon

Each offer have seperate form.
HTML is-

```
div<br>
form action="/LM" method="post"<br>
article class="itemoffer" item-offer-type="XYZ"<br>
/form
form action="/LM" method="post"<br>
form action="/LM" method="post"<br>
/div


div<br>
form action="/LM" method="post"<br>
form action="/LM" method="post"<br>
/div
```

Comment: Can you please provide HTML for which you want to count? That would be good for us to share answer, BTW, you can use Xpath to count.

Comment: updated details in question

Comment: Sorry, the HTML is still not clear

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a loop? You should be able write one xpath or css selector which returns all the elements you want in one "findElements".

Post your html and we can help find that selector